# MLflow Tracking On EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, mlflow

I'm attempting to follow the instructions given here (https://medium.com/@alexanderneshitov/how-to-run-an-mlflow-tracking-server-on-aws-ec2-d7afd0ac8008) to test running MLflow tracker on an ec2 instance. I have done the following from the article

1. Install mlflow on ec2
2. Install and configure NGINX following the steps given
3. Start mlflow server on ec2 using `mlflow server --default-artifact-root s3://test.bucket.for.mlflow/ --host 0.0.0.0`
4. Access server using its public DNS

According to the article, I should see the mlflow ui when accessing with my ec2 public DNS, but all I see is the following page:

[image: NGINX page instead of MLflow UI]

Why would I be seeing this page and not the mlflow page like:

[image]

Comment: There must be an error while starting mlflow tracking server which is why nginx is showing default page. Can you please share your mlfow log.

Comment: @JMV12, please answer this question with what has worked for you.

Comment: [not related to the question] @JMV12, that article has been deleted. so, as you had summarised, that article starts with installing mlflow on the ec2 instance and starting mlflow server, then installing nginx, then opening that nginx port 80/443 for the mlflow server to be accessed from public IP of your instance. is that all the article mentions?

Comment: wouldn't launching the mlflow server at IP 0.0.0.0 not also open the mlflow server to the internet? and i don't think you want that. and mlflow also suggests against it here: https://mlflow.org/docs/0.2.0/tracking.html#networking

Comment: i am no web developer or backend engieer. but i think might be a good practice is, you start mlflow server at localhost:5000, and use nginx as a proxy to the server at port 5000. and expose nginx at port 80 or 443 (for http/https) and you can then access the mlflow server from public internet via just the IP.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify --port options while starting mlflow. The port would be 80/443.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and posting here for others facing the same issue. I followed the page here to create an nginx proxy

https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/how-to-configure-nginx-reverse-proxy/

From step 2 on the link

2. Disable the default virtual host, that is pre-configured when Nginx is installed via Ubuntu’s packet manager apt:

   `unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
3. Enter the directory /etc/nginx/sites-available and create a reverse proxy configuration file.

   `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available`

   `nano reverse-proxy.conf`
4. Paste the following Nginx configuration in the text editor. The proxy server redirects all incomming connections on port 80 to the MLflow server, listening on port 5000.

   ```
   server {

          listen 80;
          listen [::]:80;
          access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
          error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

          location / {
                     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                     auth_basic “Restricted Content”;
                     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
          }
   }
   ```

Note: Accesses and errors are located in a log files at /var/log/nginx.

5. Copy the configuration from /etc/nginx/sites-available to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. It is recommended to use a symbolic link.

   `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf`
6. Test the Nginx configuration file

   `nginx -t`

Comment: what if i want to run mlflow server on /mlflow instead of / ?